# Copy constructor doesn't work when shared_ptr is passed as a parameter

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

Recently, I wanted to go from raw pointers to smart pointers in my code (note that it used to work without any problems with raw pointers).

Now, I have a problem with the copy constructor.

Let say that I want to create a new Frame shared_ptr like this (with `f1` being a `std::shared_ptr<Frame>` object):

```
std::shared_ptr<Frame> global_frame_1 = std::make_shared<Frame>(f1->duplicateFrame());
```

The copy constructor of the `Frame` object is defined as follows:

```
Frame::Frame(const Frame& frame) {
    m_joints = frame.m_joints;
}
```

It then gives me the following error, in the file where the first line of code I provided is located:
`C2664  'Frame::Frame(const Frame &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_Ty' to 'const std::shared_ptr<Frame>'` 
*Please note that since the compiler doesn't point me to a specific line in my code (but rather a line in the `xmemory` file), I can only guess, after looking at the specified line in the file, that these kind of assignment are the problem I'm facing.*

I first thought that I needed a copy constructor that would take a `std::shared_ptr<Frame>`, so I implemented one:

```
Frame::Frame(const std::shared_ptr<Frame> frame) {
    m_joints = frame->m_joints;
}
```

But now it gives me the same error in the `Frame` file.

It seems that I don't fully understand either how constructor copy works, or how shared_ptr works (probably both). Could someone give me a hint about what's wrong and how could I fix this?

Cheers!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The problem seems to be how `duplicateFrame` is defined rather than in the places you have been looking. Could you add that to your post.

Comment: Maybe you just want `std::shared_ptr<Frame> global_frame_1 = f1->duplicateFrame();`? Does `duplicateFrame` return a shared pointer?

Comment: If `Frame` already has a copy ctor (and assuming `f1` points to a `Frame` rather than some derived type) why not simply use `auto global_frame_1 = std::make_shared<Frame>(*f1);` ?

Comment: @Kevin find out the solution. Indeed, I modified all of my functions to return a shared pointer, so no need to use std::make_shared<T> again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use raw pointer, you probably should use `std::unique_ptr` as replacement instead of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: The compiler points you to where it noticed the error. Then it gives you a series of notes that tell you what it was doing when it found the error. Work your way back through the notes until you find one that points into your code. Yes, it's tedious, but it's something you have to learn to do.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find the actual compiler output, not the sanitized list you are apparently looking at.

The real compiler output includes a pile of lines where the tdmplate with the error is instantiated in.  This is going to be code-salad.  But eventually the chain will end at a line of your code.  Look at it, and look at the final error.  Your line of code is causing that final error.

---

So, make shared is a helper function that takes constructor parameters for a T, and builds a brand new T in a block of memory adjacent to a reference counting block.

Pass `*ptr` if you really want a copy.  But shared ptr should only be used when you want actual shared ownership.

Switch to unique ptr and use make unique and dereference the pointer.

This does mean when you have a non.owning reference you need to use a raw pointer.  But using shared ptr when you don't have shared ownership "because you don't want to think about it" is worse.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Kevin pointed it [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480404/copy-constructor-doesnt-work-when-shared-ptr-is-passed-as-a-parameter#comment115766796_65480404): I didn't need to do the whole `std::shared_ptr<Frame> global_frame_1 = std::make_shared<Frame>(f1->duplicateFrame())` thing, since I modified the `duplicateFrame()` method to already return a shared pointer. Replacing it with `std::shared_ptr<Frame> global_frame_1 = f1->duplicateFrame();` did the trick. Thanks a lot!